# Decompose a sum of positive integers into a given number of sums, each divisible by any of these integers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, graph-theory

The following curious problem I have encountered in the context of closed paths in a (special) directed graph.
At first glance, the claim seems rather strong but I think the condition on divisibility of $M$ might be the key.

Suppose we have positive integers $s_1,\dots, s_k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $M\in \mathbb{N}$ with the properties that $s_i\mid M$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$, and $\sum_{i=1}^k s_i = nM$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
Prove or disprove: There exists a partition of $\{1,\dots,k\}$ into sets $I_1,\dots, I_n$ such that $\sum_{i\in I_j}s_i= M$ for each $j=1,\dots, n$.

This problem seems to call for a version of the *pidgeon hole principle*.
Suppose we have distributed $s_{i_1},\dots, s_{i_\ell}$ over $n$ “pots” such that the sum of the “contents” of at least one “pot” is less than $M$.
I am trying to find an argument that for any remaining $s'\not \in \{s_{i_1},\dots s_{i_\ell}\}$, we can find a “pot” to which $s'$ can be added without overflowing it (rendering the respective sum $>M$).
We may assume that $s_1\geq \dots \geq s_k$, $i_1=1,\dots, i_\ell=\ell$ and $s'=s_{\ell+1}$. In particular, $\min\{s_1,\dots, s_\ell\}\geq \max\{s_{\ell+1},\dots, s_k\}$. Yet, I am unable to figure out how to proceed.

I seem to be missing something.
Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: If $M\mid s_i$ for all $i$, then $s_i \ge M$ for all $i$. So for $\sum_i\in{I_j} s_i = M, I_j$ can have at most one element, and for that $i \in I_j$ we must have $s_i = M$. This is only possible when each of the $s_i = M$, in which case $I_j = \{j\}$ for all $j$. Or did you mean $s_i \mid M$ for all $i$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair  Thank you for pointing out the typo. The divisibility assumption is $s_i \mid M$ for all $i=1, \dots, k$. I have edited the question correspondingly.

Comment: Oh well. While I figured that had to be the case, the other problem was *so easy*!

Comment: Say you have $s=\{3,3,2,2,2\}$, so $M=6,\;n=2$, then you put 3 in one pot and another 3 in another pot, and then you are stuck. No, it is not quite as simple.